# how do references work at a lower level

Tags: vb.net

I understand the concept of references at compile time, however not at runtime.

for example, if a.dll references b.dll then a.dll can use everything in b.dll. How does this work at the msil/assembly language level? Does a.asm contain a reference to b.asm or does a.asm contain all code from a.dll and b.dll?

Answer (score 0):

A reference is just an instruction that one assembly is allowed to use another assembly. The code from the referenced assembly is not copied.

The exception is constants. If the referenced assembly has a constant defined and the first assembly uses that constant, then the actual value will end up in the compiled code, not a pointer to the constant. If you change the constant, you have to recompile any code that uses it, not only the assembly where you defined the constant.

Comment: Thanks. References are stored in the project file (.vbproj) in visual studio. Are they stored in the dll/exe once compiled?

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, the executable has to contain information about the libaries that needs to be loaded.